# passenger failing to start application due to a gem on gihub

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I have a rails app that I uploaded to a server that uses Passenger. The error that is produced is:

```
compile error PATH TO GEM FILE/Gemfile:28: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND ...ery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rail... ^
```

In the gem file, I have this:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'
```

which is the line it is failing on.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Ruby 1.8 on your server? That's an error I see often when people try to use Ruby 1.9 hash syntax (eg `foo: 'bar'` instead of `:foo => 'bar'`) when Ruby 1.8 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby version matters. On the server, I have 1.8.7 and the syntax should be:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'
```